# Go to Switch user screen instead of Lock screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, script, ubuntu-14.04, screensaver

I am using `pam-usb` to login and logout when I insert and remove key. I want to lock the user out (but do not end the session). 
So I used this to lock me out:

> `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

But pam-usb does not allow to to login (without password) from the user lock screen, I have to manually go to Switch user and log in (without password).

I also tried logging out but it ends the session. So is there a way to send the user to the switch user screen with a script?